# Getting the time between two values with a join

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Example of my DB:**

```
ID     APP     USER_ID    SESSION_ID  LOCAL_TIME  CONTEXT  ACTION       VALUE
141    App1    userID1     session1   2019-07-18   Player   Name      PlayerName1
141    App1    userID1     session1   2019-07-18   Player    XP          486
141    App1    userID1     session2   2019-07-18   App     BuildNum     11184
452    App1    userID4     session1   2019-07-18   Player   Name      PlayerName2
452    App1    userID4     session1   2019-07-18   State    Start     PlayerName2
452    App1    userID4     session1   2019-07-18   State    End       PlayerName2
```

What I would like to do is find the total time between `Context = state`, `action = end` and `Context = state`, `action = start` with the same `SESSION_ID`.

The reason I need to look for the `action = end` first is because end is only logged if they stay around for the end of the match.

The problem I am having is that the two values are part of the same Context and action Entities and I am not great with EAV DB's.

**Example of Desired Data:**

```
SESSION_ID     Play Length of session (Time between action=start & action=End
          23                 32
         215                 16
         352                 51
```

Thanks for any and all help, I really appreciate it and I hope this was clear enough.
Take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below query.  It uses the `max()` with a filter to determine what to subtract from the records with `action` of `End`.

```
with playtimes as (
  select session_id, 
         case
           when action = 'End' 
             then local_time - max(local_time) 
               filter (where action = 'Start')
                 over (partition by session_id
                           order by local_time)
           else null
         end as session_length         
    from your_table
   where context = 'State'
     and action in ('Start', 'End')
   group by session_id
)
select session_length, 
       round(extract(epoch from session_length) / 60) as session_minutes
  from playtimes
 where session_length is not null;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just wish it was minutes only, but this worked great!

Thanks!

Comment: @Se_7_eN  I updated the query to convert the interval to minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a simple join from your eav table with itself:

```
select 
  session_id,
  max(end_time) - min(start_time) as length_of_session --## min/max only needed if there might be multiple entries
from (
  select
    session_id,
    local_time as end_time
  from eav
  where context = 'State' and action = 'End'
) e
join ( 
  select
    session_id,
    local_time as start_time
  from eav
  where context = 'State' and action = 'Start'
) s using (session_id) --## join based on session_id
group by session_id;
```